# Split string by comma and space or space

Tags: python, regex

I have two example strings, which I would like to split by either ", " (if , is present) or " ".

```
x = ">Keratyna 5, egzon 2, Homo sapiens"
y = ">101m_A mol:protein length:154  MYOGLOBIN"
```

The split should be performed just once to recover two pieces of information:

```
id, description = re.split(pattern, string, maxsplit=1)
```

For `">Keratyna 5, egzon 2, Homo sapiens" -> [">Keratyna 5", "egzon 2, Homo sapiens"]`

For `">101m_A mol:protein length:154  MYOGLOBIN" -> [">101m_A", "mol:protein length:154  MYOGLOBIN"]`

I came up with the following patterns:
`",\\s+|\\s+",  ",\\s+|^,\\s+",  "[,]\\s+|[^,]\\s+"`,
but none of these work.

The solution I made is using an exception:

```
try:
    id, description = re.split(",\s+", description, maxsplit=1)
except ValueError:
    id, description = re.split("\s+", description, maxsplit=1)
```

but honestly I hate this workaround. I haven't found any suitable regex pattern yet. How should I do it?

Comment: Have you tried `,?\s+`?

Comment: Please don't spam-tag irrelevant language tags. That is one way to accumulate down-votes and quickly

Comment: Yes, i have tried ,?\s+, does not work unfortunately.

Comment: Split the string on commas using `.split(",")`. Then clean up the resulting strings to remove unwanted spaces using  `.strip(" ")`.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels sorry, i thought that if my issue is actually the regex pattern which is same for most of the programming languages, i can use not only the python tag. Thank you for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could either split on the first occurrence of `,`  or split on a space that is no occurrence of `,`  to the right using an alternation:

```
, | (?!.*?, )
```

The pattern matches:

- `,`  Match `,`
- `|` Or
- `(?!.*?, )` Negative lookahead, assert that to the right is not `,`

See a [Python demo](https://ideone.com/wcONK7) and a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/TIs2en/1).

Example

```
import re

strings = [
    ">Keratyna 5, egzon 2, Homo sapiens",
    ">101m_A mol:protein length:154  MYOGLOBIN"
]

for s in strings:
    print(re.split(r", | (?!.*?, )", s, maxsplit=1))
```

Output

```
['>Keratyna 5', 'egzon 2, Homo sapiens']
['>101m_A', 'mol:protein length:154  MYOGLOBIN']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
^((?=.*,)[^,]+|\S+)[\s,]+(.*)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/0FTSwb/1). *Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `((?=.*,)[^,]+|\S+)` - Group 1: if there is a `,` after any zero or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible, then match one or more chars other than `,`, or match one or more non-whitespace chars
- `[\s,]+` - zero or more commas/whitespaces
- `(.*)` - Group 2: zero or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/Kiwrgx):

```py
import re
pattern = re.compile( r'^((?=.*,)[^,]+|\S+)[\s,]+(.*)' )
texts = [">Keratyna 5, egzon 2, Homo sapiens", ">101m_A mol:protein length:154  MYOGLOBIN"]
for text in texts:
    m = pattern.search(text)
    if m:
        id, description = m.groups()
        print(f"ID: '{id}', DESCRIPTION: '{description}'")
```

Output:

```
ID: '>Keratyna 5', DESCRIPTION: 'egzon 2, Homo sapiens'
ID: '>101m_A', DESCRIPTION: 'mol:protein length:154  MYOGLOBIN'
```